# Can there be blocks within blocks in jade?

Tags: pug, template-engine

Can I have a layout.jade file:

```
h1 Layout File  
 block content
```

And then an index.jade file:

`extends layout

     .span4.whatever

         p some code goes here

     block another-code-block`

And then a third thirdfile.jade file:

`extends index

  .row-fluid

    a.poo
    a.boo`

This is not working. Nor is having both extend layout. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works

Layout

```
 h1 Layout File  
 block content  //this is block content
```

Index

```
extends layout //extend layout..
block content  //... at the block "content"
    .span4.whatever
    block asdasd  //this is block asdasd
```

Thirdfile

```
extends index //extend index
block asdasd //at block "asdasd" (so it replaces asdasd and everything in "asdasd")
    .span5.whatever
```

Comment: in my newer projects i cant stack more then three blocks within each other... got no idea why it suddenly limits me to three... if u find an answere tell me ;)